# Fixed footer is covering content in page

Tags: html, css

I added a footer in which it is not reaching the bottom of the page and is covering content from my website, here is a picture of this problem. the footer covers text from underneath the two images. Is there any way for the footer to always remain at the bottom; not covering any extra content added in the future.

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
            $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
      });
});

// Scrolling Effect

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop()) {
            $('nav').addClass('black');
      }

      else {
            $('nav').removeClass('black');
      }
})
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 200px;

}
#main {

    padding-bottom: 100px;

}


body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

#Header-1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 35px;
}




.content {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
    line-height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index:2;
}

nav ul {
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

    .logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 16px;
}

    nav ul {
        max-height: 0px;
        background: #000;

    }

    nav.black ul {
        background: #000;
    }

    .showing {
        max-height: 34em;
    }

    nav ul li {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

}

.container {

    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 24px;
    object-fit: cover;

}

.parallax {
    background: url('images/background-1.jpeg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 500px;
    min-height: 400px;
    z-index:-1;


}


p {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    margin: 2.5%;
    padding:0;
}
.b1{
    text-align: center;
}


.pic-1{
    height:280px; 
    width:420px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 100px;
}


.pic-2{
    height:280px; 
    width:420px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 100px;  

}

/*----------footer------------*/

#footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#222;
    padding: 60px 0px;
    position: relative;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Croydon Cycles</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="parallax.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
          <header>

                <nav>

                      <div class="menu-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                      </div>

                      <div class="logo">
                            Croydon Cycles 
                      </div>

                      <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                      </div>
                </nav>

          </header>
    <div id="content">
          <div id="main">
                <div class="container">



                      <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="-1">






                      </div>

                      <div class="content">
                            <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
                            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
                            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
                            Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
                            however we still are active around all of Croydon.
                            </p>
                      </div>
                </div>

                <div class="profiles">

                      <p id="Header-1">Here are some of the members of Croydon Cycles:</p>

                      <div class="pic-1">
                      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/09/10/08/saddle-2614038_960_720.jpg" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
                      <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
                                  all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
                                  road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
                                  Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
                                  however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>
                      </div>



                      <div class="pic-2">
                      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/03/23/19/bike-190483_960_720.jpg" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
                      <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
                            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
                            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
                            Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
                            however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>


    <footer id="footer">


    </footer>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but do you want the footer to always be present? or just the bottom of the site?

Comment: just to be at the bottom of the site

Comment: Issue looks to be with the css style .pic-1 and .pic-2.  By having a hard coded height the img and p tags exceed the height of the parent without expanding it.  Two possible solutions: 1) add an overflow-y:auto to the .pic-2 and .pic-2 or; 2) remove the height attribute from .pic-1 and .pic-2

Comment: I added the overflow-y:auto to pic-1 and pic-2 and removed the height attribute but the footer did not come down. Do I need to change anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the example below. I've added comments to the changes made

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".menu-icon").on("click", function() {
            $("nav ul").toggleClass("showing");
      });
});

// Scrolling Effect

$(window).on("scroll", function() {
      if($(window).scrollTop()) {
            $('nav').addClass('black');
      }

      else {
            $('nav').removeClass('black');
      }
})
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Instead of a margin or bottom set nothing unless recuired. Better to use padding  */
#content {
    min-height: 100%;
    position: relative;

}
#main {

    padding-bottom: 100px;

}


body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
}

#Header-1 {
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    font-size: 35px;
}




.content {
    width: 94%;
    margin: 4em auto;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: justify;
}

.logo {
    line-height: 60px;
    position: fixed;
    float: left;
    margin: 16px 46px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 60px;
    z-index:2;
}

nav ul {
    line-height: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: right;
    margin: 0;
    padding-right: 40px;
    transition: 1s;
}

nav.black ul {
    background: #000;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 16px 40px;;
}

nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.menu-icon {
    line-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    text-align: right;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 15px 24px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    display: none;
}

@media(max-width: 786px) {

    .logo {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        margin-top: 16px;
}

    nav ul {
        max-height: 0px;
        background: #000;

    }

    nav.black ul {
        background: #000;
    }

    .showing {
        max-height: 34em;
    }

    nav ul li {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 100%;
        padding: 24px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: block;
    }

}

.container {

    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #f9f9f9;
    font-size: 24px;
    object-fit: cover;

}

.parallax {
    background: url('images/background-1.jpeg') no-repeat center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 500px;
    min-height: 400px;
    z-index:-1;


}


p {
    font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;
    margin: 2.5%;
    padding:0;
}
.b1{
    text-align: center;
}

/* Remove hard coded height  */
.pic-1{ 
    width:420px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 100px;
}


.pic-2{
    width:420px;
    float: right;
    padding-right: 100px;  

}

/*----------footer------------*/
/* Set to position relative and bottom 0 */
#footer {
    width:100%;
    background-color:#222;
    padding: 60px 0px;
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 0;
    clear:both;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>Croydon Cycles</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="images/favicon.png">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Karla" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="parallax.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper">
          <header>

                <nav>

                      <div class="menu-icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
                      </div>

                      <div class="logo">
                            Croydon Cycles 
                      </div>

                      <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                  <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>
                                  <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                            </ul>
                      </div>
                </nav>

          </header>
    <div id="content">
          <div id="main">
                <div class="container">



                      <div class="parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-z-index="-1">






                      </div>

                      <div class="content">
                            <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
                            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
                            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
                            Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
                            however we still are active around all of Croydon.
                            </p>
                      </div>
                </div>

                <div class="profiles">

                      <p id="Header-1">Here are some of the members of Croydon Cycles:</p>

                      <div class="pic-1">
                      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2017/08/09/10/08/saddle-2614038_960_720.jpg" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
                      <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
                                  all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
                                  road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
                                  Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
                                  however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>
                      </div>



                      <div class="pic-2">
                      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/10/03/23/19/bike-190483_960_720.jpg" alt="Proffesional biker"  height="280px" width="420px">
                      <p>The Croydon Cycles was founded in 2001 in order to promote and encourage 
                            all areas of cyclesports. The club has a rich history of racing both on the 
                            road and track. We also have an active social side and regular training trips away. 
                            Croydon Cycles is located in mostly around Thornton heath pond, 
                            however we still are active around all of Croydon.</p>
                      </div>
                </div>
          </div>
    </div>
     <footer id="footer">


    </footer>
  </div>


   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have made all the changes you have told me, the footer has now appeared at the bottom thank you so much for your time and help.